# Disable Past Dates and 2 days ahead and Mondays and Sundays in datepicker

Tags: javascript, html

Hello i need help solving how to disable past dates and 2 future dates plus disable Monday and Sunday from html date-picker, At the moment the currect code disables past dates and 1 future day but i would like to disable Monday and Sunday as well Please help.

```
<label>Pickup Date : </label></b>                                                       
<input class="datepicker" type="date" name="delivery_date" id="txtDate" pattern="" required /> 

    
<script>                                                    
$(function(){
    var dtToday = new Date();
    
    var month = dtToday.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = dtToday.getDate() + 2;
    var year = dtToday.getFullYear();
    if(month < 10)
        month = '0' + month.toString();
    if(day < 10)
        day = '0' + day.toString();
    
    var maxDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;

    // or instead:
    // var maxDate = dtToday.toISOString().substr(0, 10);


    $('#txtDate').attr('min', maxDate);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sadly that is not possible with the HTML date picker the most you can do is disable past days + 2 and then validate the input to ensure the user doesn't pick a Monday or Sunday.

Here is an example... I hope it helps

https://codepen.io/freckless/pen/dyayqoo

```
<label>Pickup Date : </label></b>                                                       
<input class="datepicker" type="date" name="delivery_date" id="txtDate" pattern="" required /> 
    
<script>
  function formatDate(date) {
    return date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate();
  }
  
  // Prevent picking past days + 2
  const notBefore = new Date
  notBefore.setDate(notBefore.getDate() + 2);
  document.getElementById('txtDate').min = formatDate(notBefore);
  
  // Avoid monday or sunday by validating the picked date...
  document.getElementById('txtDate').addEventListener('change', function(ev) {
    const date = new Date(ev.target.value);
    if (date.getDay() <= 1) { // Sunday = 0, Monday = 1
        alert('Monday and sunday are not valid dates');
        ev.target.value = null;
    }
  });
</script>
```